# Join two dataframe based on time interval

Tags: python, sql, merge

Is there a way to join two tables using one table's timestamp difference to match another table's timestamp. For example, for one table I have start and end timestamps, I want to match other tables timestamp in the difference between start and end times.

table1

```
start_time         end_time          ID  Ident
01/01/2022 17:56   01/01/2022 17:59  1   1A
01/01/2022 18:36   01/01/2022 18:40  2   1C
01/01/2022 19:48   01/01/2022 19:50  1   2D
01/01/2022 20:12   01/01/2022 20:14  2   4F
01/01/2022 21:47   01/01/2022 21:50  3   7R
01/01/2022 22:56   01/01/2022 22:59  5   2E
01/01/2022 23:57   01/01/2022 23:59  6   3E
```

Table2

```
Timestamp         rate
01/01/2022 17:57  5
01/01/2022 19:49  5  
01/01/2022 20:14  5
01/01/2022 21:47  5
01/01/2022 23:58  5
```

result

```
start_time         end_time          ID Timestamp         rate
01/01/2022 17:56   01/01/2022 17:59  1  01/01/2022 17:57  5
01/01/2022 18:36   01/01/2022 18:40  2  null              null
01/01/2022 19:48   01/01/2022 19:50  1  01/01/2022 19:49  5
01/01/2022 20:12   01/01/2022 20:14  2  01/01/2022 20:14  5
01/01/2022 21:47   01/01/2022 21:50  3  01/01/2022 21:47  5
01/01/2022 22:56   01/01/2022 22:59  5  null              null
01/01/2022 23:57   01/01/2022 23:59  6  01/01/2022 23:58  5
```

I tried to use pandas.merge_asof in Python but the problem I'm having is there are duplicate rows for the right table in the result if the time is too close which I don't want. Is there a way to do this without duplication maybe in SQL? I have tried inner join but I not getting any change from the table so maybe I did it wrong. This is the code I used

```
SELECT *
FROM Table 1
inner Table 2
on Table 2.Timestamp
between Table1.Start_Stamp and Table1.END_TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: What's the exact type of your timestamp columns ? What is the database engine you're using ? The between clause may work depending on the data type of the timestamp columns, but you have an error on your join clause. But to better answer your question we need a few more details.

Comment: @Davidroid, thanks. The timestamp column is text and I'm using MySQL InnoDB.